# Como desenvolver com Cooldown com o Express-Session

Tags: node.js, session, express.js

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de envio de feedbacks. A pessoa preenche alguns dados, envia e salva no banco de dados. Porém, por questão de segurança, queria criar um cooldown para que a pessoa só envie outro feedback após 24h por exemplo. Tentei fazer criando `sessions`, mas nenhum que funcionasse corretamente. Alguém tem uma ideia?

**Controller:**

````js
router.post('/send-feedback', (req, res) => {

    const { name, email, description } = req.body

    Feedback.create({
        client_name: name,
        client_email: email,
        client_feedback: description
    }).then(() => {

        req.flash('success', 'Muito obrigado pelo Feedback, é muito importante para mim!')
        return res.redirect('/feedback')

    })


})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mais seguro ai, é você salvar no banco quando foi a ultima vez que a pessoa (email) enviou um feedback.
ai antes de aceitar, você verifica se já passou mais de 24h, desde o ultimo registro daquela pessoa na base.

com sessão não fica legal, pois ela pode apagar cookies, usar outro dispositivo, etc.

Comment: Mas tipo, se o usuário mudar o email? Ai tecnicamente ele poderia floodar

Comment: sim, sempre é burlável, não existe sistema 100% seguro.
ai você parte para uma chave múltipla: email + ip + cookie, e por ai vai.